How many islands can papa Smurf visit at most?
An island nation has $n$ islands. In the beginning every two islands are connected by a bridge. Papa Smurf starts out on island $A$ and wants to visit all other islands however Gargamel is trying to stop him. Whenever papa Smurf comes to an island, Gargamel destroys $k$ bridges coming out of that island. (if the remaining bridges are less than $k$ then he destroys all remaining bridges)
Depending on $n$ and $k$ how many islands can papa Smurf visit at most (without repeating any) regardless of Gargamel’s actions?
My attempt at a solution is as follows:
In the beginning the island nation is the graph $K_n$ and the starting island $A$ can be any vertex. Since the degree of all vertices is $n-1$ it follows that if $k\ge n-1$ then after papa Smurf visits his first island Gargamel will destroy all outgoing bridges meaning he won’t be able to go anywhere. Now if $k < n-1$, papa Smurf can always construct a Hamilton path since the island nation is a complete graph. Then we consider the best case scenario in which Gargamel breaks only the bridges papa Smurf doesn’t need (there will always be 1 bridge left at least and WOLOG we can consider that bridge to be the one we need). Under these conditions papa Smurf can visit all $n$ islands. So finally we can say: If $k\ge n-1$ then papa Smurf can visit only $2$ islands including $A$. If $k<n-1$ then papa Smurf can visit all $n$ islands.
I’m not sure my argument for $k<n-1$ is correct. I’d like help with that part.

“Then we consider the best case scenario in which Gargamel breaks only the bridges papa Smurf doesn’t need”. You can’t assume this. Gargamel wants Smurf to fail. You can’t assume he’ll try to help. WLOG doesn’t work like that.

@Eric what can i do then? i assumed if we look at all possible ways in which Gargamel is breaking bridges then papa Smurf will reach the most islands when Gargamel is not affecting his path in any way by breaking all the wrong bridges

But this is not a solution "regardless of Gargamel's actions". All Gargamel has to do is destroy the one bridge Papa Smurf was going to take next. So to get more than two islands, Papa must have a strategy to choose a path that changes based on what Gargamel does. Similarly, Gargamel gets to choose which bridges to destroy based on what Papa Smurf does.

@aschepler yes you’re right. i was taking his actions into account by saying we can consider the ‘best case scenario’

If $k < n-1$, then Papa Smurf can always reach at least $n-k$ islands, and Gargamel can always prevent Papa Smurf from reaching $n-k+1$ islands.
For Papa Smurf's strategy, he can simply choose at each step to go to an island he hasn't been to yet, if possible.
Suppose Papa has so far visited $m-1$ different islands $I_1, I_2, \ldots, I_{m-1}$ in order without repeats, and now arrives at an unvisited island $I_m$. Of the $n-1$ bridges originally connected to island $I_m$, Gargamel could only have destroyed the bridges connected to previously visited islands, so there are still bridges from $I_m$ to each of the $n-m$ unvisited islands. Now Gargamel may destroy $k$ bridges connected to $I_m$, but if $k<n-m$, there is still at least one bridge to some unvisited island, so Papa may continue. So this simple strategy works at least until $m=n-k$; that is, Papa will be able to visit at least $n-k$ different islands.
For Gargamel's strategy, after Papa Smurf's first move from $I_1$ to $I_2$, Gargamel will choose a set $S$ of any $k$ islands which does not include $I_1$ or $I_2$. At every chance, Gargamel will destroy all $k$ of the bridges from Papa's current island to each island in $S$. Or if Papa had already visited his current island and it's not $I_1$, then those bridges are already destroyed and Gargamel can choose any other bridges from the island.
With this strategy, Papa can never reach any of the $k$ islands in $S$, so he cannot reach more than $n-k$ islands.

Suppose $n=4$ and the islands are $A,B,C,D$. Starting at $A$ Smurf goes to $B$. Gargamel destroys the $2 < 4-1$ bridges to $C,D$, so Smurf must return to $A$. Then Gargamel destroys the bridges to $C,D$ and Smurf is stuck at $A,B$.
In general, after Smurf's first move, Gargamel can use his $k$ explosions on each turn to destroy the bridges leading to the same $k$ islands, restricting Smurf to $n-k$ islands.

This is how I would approach this. We assume a worst case scenario for Papa Smurf in the sense that Gargamel, will never delete bridges, that lead back to islands that Papa Smurf already visited.
If $k\ge n-2 $ then he can visit at most $2$ islands, that is $A$ and the first one he goes to.
Let us assume $n>k+2$ and let us denote $\ell(n)$ as the number of islands that can be visited. Let us also assume that Gargamel can delete edges even before we have left island $A$, this makes the following recursion clearer. In our scenario $\ell(n) = \ell(n-1) + 1$ for all $n>k+2$, and $\ell(k+2) = 2$. Then inductively $\ell(n) = \ell(k+2) + n - (k+2) = n-k$. So my answer would be $\max \{2,n-k\}$ for the number of islands that can be visited.

You seem to be using $n$ for more than one thing, when $n$ is a given for the problem.

It's an inductive proof over the number of islands $n$, this is what I use it for. Do you think it is incorrect?

Maybe to clarify, we consider $n$ islands and a starting point $A$, now if we move away from that island, we can consider the remaining islands and the current island papa Smurf is on as the same problem for $n-1$ islands. At least I think that's why an inductive proof should work here. Maybe I'm missing something.

Okay, I see how you mean it now. You didn't really explain the claim that $n>k+2$ implies $\ell(n)=\ell(n-1)+1$. (And you mean "delete edges", not "delete vertices".)

why do you consider cases depending on $k$ compared to $n-2$ instead of $n-1$?

To answer the previous two comments: Yes I meant delete vertices, thank you for pointing that out, I will edit the answer. I consider $k$ compared to $n-2$, because the proof assumes a worst case scenario for Papa Smurf. The worst case scenario for him if $k\ge n-2$ is the following: He starts at island $A$ and goes to any other island among the other $n-1$, once he is there Gargamel deletes all bridges to the $n-2$ islands he did not visit yet, this is a worst case scenario, because if $k=n-2$ Gargamel might also make the mistake of deleting the bridge back to $A$ and leaving another option.
